# How do I compare two large table get mismatch data in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, validation, merge, compare

Suppose I have two large tables (1,000,000 rows each) with multiple keys (assume id and name as keys)

Table A

| id | Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1.00 |
| 2 | Apple | 2.00 |
| 3 | Orange | 1.00 |
| 4 | Orange | 2.00 |
| 5 | Banana | 3.00 |

Table B

| id | Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1.00 |
| 2 | Apple | 3.00 |
| 3 | Orange | 1.00 |
| 4 | Orange | 4.00 |
| 5 | Banana | 3.00 |

And I want the result to return the value from Table A that the price does not match with

Table B

Result Table:

| id | Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Apple | 2.00 |
| 4 | Orange | 2.00 |

How would I get the result above without enduring long processing time on Python?

Comment: Hi Pchapr and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question will be hard to answer without a little more information. (1) what have your tried? (2) what do you mean by 'long processing time'. How would someone replying know that their answer is fast enough to be a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
result = df1.loc[(df1 != df2).any(1)]
```

output:

```
   id    Name  Price
1   2   Apple    2.0
3   4  Orange    2.0
```